# T-SQL MAX function alternatives

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I currently have this query that returns the most recent IDs in a table:

```
SELECT StatusUpdates.ForeignId,
StatusUpdates.DateUpdated AS MostRecentChange
FROM hjStatusUpdates StatusUpdates
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ForeignId,
    MAX(DateUpdated) AS MostRecentChange
    FROM hjStatusUpdates
    GROUP BY ForeignId) DerivedTable
    ON StatusUpdates.ForeignId = DerivedTable.ForeignId
    AND StatusUpdates.DateUpdated = DerivedTable.MostRecentChange
WHERE StatusUpdates.ForeignTable = 'hjClientAccounts';
```

My question is, is it possible to set an upper limit on the `MAX` function, or are there better functions to use, so that I can add a "less than (date)" clause to this function?

I do not want to add something like `AND DerivedTable.MostRecentChange <= '2016-12-30 23:59:59'` to the `INNER JOIN` as this is not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129543/discussion-on-question-by-arndg2-t-sql-max-function-alternatives).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MAX(case when DateUpdated <=  '2016-12-30 23:59:59' then DateUpdated end)
```

---

#### Performance test : MAX(...) Vs. MAX(Case...)

```
with t(n) as (select 0 union all select n+1 from t where n<9)
select      getdate() - RAND(cast(NEWID() as varbinary))*365*10  as dt 
into        #t 
from        t t0,t t1,t t2,t t3,t t4,t t5,t t6,t t7
```

---

```
select max(dt) from #t
```

X 10

> Total execution time  103977 miliseconds

```
select max(case when dt <= '2016-01-01 00:00:00' then dt end) from #t
```

X 10

> Total execution time    118738 miliseconds

---

> ```
> 10 X 100M rows:                    14.761 sec
> Average difference per 100M rows:   1.476 sec
> Average difference per 1M rows:     0.015 sec
> ```

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL MAX() function supports Partition By clause just like Count, Sum or Row_Number functions, etc.

You can use MAX() as follows on a sample SQL system view

```
select distinct 
object_id, 
max(column_id) over (partition by object_id) 
from sys.columns
```

Perhaps you can use a function result or field in the place of Partition By field to get desired output